# Restore MBR on a Toshiba Satellite Click Mini laptop with Windows 8 after uninstalling Debian 8 using EasyBCD

Tags: windows-8, boot, grub, mbr, toshiba-laptop

The Toshiba Satellite Click Mini is a special computer, it doesn't have any CD/DVD drive and the BIOS is special and very limited, it looks like this:

[image: Boot menu presented]

When I select "Enter Setup" I have a menu like this:

[image: Enter setup menu]

What I've done :

1. I tried to remove a Linux Debian 8 "Jessie" installation by using EasyBCD 2.2 : in "BCD Management Options", "Re-create/repair boot files" (I've followed a video tutorial : http://youtube.com/watch?v=heO1n73Ua4Q)
2. After that, I boot and go into the BIOS (by pressing Power button + Volume up), I disable the "Secure Boot" option in the Boot Menu (see the second image).
3. I tried to boot on my USB stick with Ubuntu on it (also tried with a Windows repair disk image), but it doesn't work and it tries boots to Windows 8 everytime and the famous message pops up even if I choose my USB Stick from the Boot Menu (I can always boot to Windows 8 by reactivating the Secure Boot, it just prevents me to boot on another OS and that's pretty annoying) :

   `error: no such partition
   Entering rescue mode...
   grub rescue> _`
4. So I searched on how to resolve this and people are telling that you need to enter these commands on grub rescue screen :
   `ls` and `set`, so I tried and this appear :

   `grub rescue> ls
   (hd0) (hd1) (hd1,gpt4) (hd1,gpt3) (hd1,gpt2) (hd1,gpt1) (hd2) (hd3)`

   `grub rescue> set
   cmdpath=(hd1,gpt1)/EFI/debian
   prefix=(hd1,gpt5)/boot/grub
   root=hd1,gpt5`
5. In Windows 8 from the settings menu, I've turned off fast start-up and then I go in Advanced setup in PC settings menu/Troubleshoot/Advanced options/Command Prompt and entered the commands :

   `bootrec.exe /FixMbr
   bootrec.exe /FixBoot
   exit`

I searched everywhere on internet and didn't solve my problem,
I think the Toshiba Satellite Click Mini laptop is a special case as the BIOS menu is very limited.

Thanks in advance for you answers !

Comment: English flawless as far as I can tell. Also, you did a very good job of writing this.

Comment: ClickMini have only EFI mode boot. It does not know about MBR. Follow EFI related info in order to restore windows efi boot partition...

Comment: Funny how the firmware itself uses the term BIOS.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that tutorial was for a virtual machine that probably used a BIOS/MBR configuration, your laptop probably has a UEFI/GPT configuration. Apparently EasyBCD [doesn't support UEFI 100%](https://neosmart.net/wiki/easybcd/uefi/). The net result is that you didn't remove GRUB from your EFI partition, evident by the lines `cmdpath=(hd1,gpt1)/EFI/debian
prefix=(hd1,gpt5)/boot/grub`

To fix this boot into a Windows recovery environment (secure boot setting shouldn't matter) and [reset your efi](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows8_1-update/resetting-efi-partition-boot-partition-to-factory/0cf3d22a-792a-47dd-a0aa-0d5ac289c1d4).

To summarize that repair link, in the repair menu do:

- bootrec /RebuildBcd
- bootrec /fixMbr
- bootrec /fixboot
- bootsect /nt60 SYS
- bootsect /nt60 ALL
- Exit

You could probably also fix this from within Windows 8 too I suppose, or even using a linux livecd. If you have trouble booting into recovery, update your question. Perhaps you could include your partition information too. But normally a recovery disk can handle the job.

---

**Update:**
Sorry just noticed this question is rather old.